# parsing json object with jsonarray in android

Tags: android, json

hi hello I am new to android.I am getting response from server. But i get the following response..

getting the following error

```
Value {"Elec":"Cup1"} at 1 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

The responce is as follows

```
{"Electronics":["{\"Elec\":\"Cup0\"}","{\"Elec\":\"Cup1\"}","{\"Elec\":\"Cup2\"}","{\"Elec\":\"Cup3\"}","{\"Elec\":\"Cup4\"}","{\"Elec\":\"Cup5\"}","{\"Elec\":\"Cup6\"}","{\"Elec\":\"Cup7\"}","{\"Elec\":\"Cup8\"}","{\"Elec\":\"Cup9\"}"],"Printable":["{\"Print\":\"Mug0\"}","{\"Print\":\"Mug1\"}","{\"Print\":\"Mug2\"}","{\"Print\":\"Mug3\"}","{\"Print\":\"Mug4\"}","{\"Print\":\"Mug5\"}","{\"Print\":\"Mug6\"}","{\"Print\":\"Mug7\"}","{\"Print\":\"Mug8\"}","{\"Print\":\"Mug9\"}"]}
```

And i send and receive the responce is as follows

```
    class SliderImages extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return POST1(urls[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

}

public String POST1(String url) {
    InputStream inputStream;
    String result = "";
    try {
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();


        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();
        Log.d("JsonStringSend", json);
        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if (inputStream != null) {
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            Log.d("JSONResponce", result);
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
            contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Electronics");
            for (int i = 1; i < contacts.length()-1; i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("Print");
                Log.e("Errrrrrrr",""+id);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // 11. return result
    return result;
}


private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;
    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

So the get the following error

```
Value {"Elec":"Cup1"} at 1 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: see my answer.....

Answer (score 2):

This is the result after formatting your json in jsoneditoronline.org

[image]

Notice that the objects inside the 'Electronics' array are not `JSONObject` but `String` instead.

A simple workaround would be to get the object as a `String` first then parse it into a `JSONObject` like:

```
    // 10. convert inputstream to string
    if (inputStream != null) {
        result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        Log.d("JSONResponce", result);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
        contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Electronics");

        // Note contacts.length() NOT contacts.length() - 1
        for (int i = 1; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

            String cString = contacts.getString(i);
            JSONObject c = new JSONObject(cString);

            String id = c.getString("Print");
            Log.e("Errrrrrrr",""+id);
        }
    }
```

The best option would be however to correct the data returned from the server.

Comment: what is c string inside for loop

Comment: I have one ,more problem

Comment: what should i do when there are more values in electronic

Comment: @LoadMore What do you mean by 'more values'. The code will still work because you're iterating through and accessing the array by index.

Answer (score 0):

for (int i = 1; i < contacts.length()-1; i++)

to

for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++)

Answer (score 0):

Instead calling **getString** or **getJsonObject** use **jsonObject.get(key)** and check the instance like below.

```
Object obj = jsonObject.get(key);
if(obj instanceof String) {
   // retrieve the string
} else if(obj instanceof JsonObject) {
    // retrieve the Json object
}
```

To get the values from **JsonObject** use **jsonObject.optString** or **.optJsonObject**, instead **jsonObject.getString** or **.getJsonObject**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        String response = "{\"Electronics\":[\"{\\\"Elec\\\":\\\"Cup0\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Elec\\\":\\\"Cup1\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Elec\\\":\\\"Cup2\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Elec\\\":\\\"Cup3\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Elec\\\":\\\"Cup4\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Elec\\\":\\\"Cup5\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Elec\\\":\\\"Cup6\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Elec\\\":\\\"Cup7\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Elec\\\":\\\"Cup8\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Elec\\\":\\\"Cup9\\\"}\"],\"Printable\":[\"{\\\"Print\\\":\\\"Mug0\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Print\\\":\\\"Mug1\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Print\\\":\\\"Mug2\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Print\\\":\\\"Mug3\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Print\\\":\\\"Mug4\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Print\\\":\\\"Mug5\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Print\\\":\\\"Mug6\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Print\\\":\\\"Mug7\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Print\\\":\\\"Mug8\\\"}\",\"{\\\"Print\\\":\\\"Mug9\\\"}\"]}";

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray Electronics = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Electronics");
        JSONArray Printable = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Printable");

        for (int i = 1; i < Electronics.length(); i++) {

            String cString = Electronics.getString(i);
            JSONObject c = new JSONObject(cString);
            String Elec = c.getString("Elec");
            Log.e("Elec", "" + Elec);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < Printable.length(); i++) {

            String cString = Printable.getString(i);
            JSONObject c = new JSONObject(cString);
            String Print = c.getString("Print");
            System.out.println(" Print --> " + Print);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(" time error --> " + e.toString());
    }
```

Logcat,

> 07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc E/Elec: Cup1
>   07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc E/Elec: Cup2
>   07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc E/Elec: Cup3
>   07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc E/Elec: Cup4
>   07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc E/Elec: Cup5
>   07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc E/Elec: Cup6
>   07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc E/Elec: Cup7
>   07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc E/Elec: Cup8
>   07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc E/Elec: Cup9
>   07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc I/System.out: 
>   Print --> Mug1 07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc
>   I/System.out:  Print --> Mug2 07-23 01:48:12.808
>   8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc I/System.out:  Print --> Mug3 07-23
>   01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc I/System.out:  Print
>   --> Mug4 07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc I/System.out:  Print --> Mug5 07-23 01:48:12.808
>   8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc I/System.out:  Print --> Mug6 07-23
>   01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc I/System.out:  Print
>   --> Mug7 07-23 01:48:12.808 8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc I/System.out:  Print --> Mug8 07-23 01:48:12.808
>   8134-8134/com.example.peacock.abc I/System.out:  Print --> Mug9

I hope u solve your problem soon....